# free pointers not working even though they're allocated

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory, free

I have two pointers in my program which freeing them doesn't work, I don't get an error of any sort, just an error sound from visual studio..
The program runs perfectly fine if I don't free them (but I know I must do that).
This is my code with everything that uses those two pointers, hopefully you'll help me.

```
void gameProcess(char *word, int len) 
{
    int i, letterExist, life = 7, temp;
    char *pGuess, *bank, c;
    if (!(bank = (char*)malloc(N)))
        printf("Error!! Allocated memory failure!");
    bank[N] = '\0';
    if (!(pGuess = (char*)malloc(len)))
        printf("Error!! Allocated memory failure!");
    pGuess[len] = '\0';
    guessVisual(pGuess);
    while (life > 0 && len > 0)
    {
        letterExist = 0;
        printf("\n\nEnter your guess please:\n");
        c = guessInterface(word, pGuess, bank);
        letterExist = checkIfExist(word, c, len);
        temp = replaceIfExist(word, c, pGuess);
        if (letterExist > 0)
            len = rightGuess(pGuess, len, temp);
        else
            life = wrongGuess(life);
        if (len == 0)
            win();
        if (life == 0)
            lose();
    }
    free(pGuess);//***************
    free(bank);//***************
}
```

Thank you!
If any other info is needed, let me know.

Comment: Please rewrite this so that it does not need other functions, but still reproduces the error. In short, create a [mcve]

Comment: If you can run [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) on your machine, do so.  But writing outside the bounds of your allocated arrays is bad news.  It's odd that you try to write a null byte at the end; the data before it is indeterminate.  Maybe you should use `bank[0] = '\0';` and `pGuess[0] = '\0';` so that you have zero length strings in a bigger allocated space.  Since we can't see most of the functions you call, we can't tell what damage is being done by them — hence the request for an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: Until you correct the *undefined behaviour* in `bank[N] = '\0';` and `pGuess[len] = '\0';` all bets are off.

Comment: Compiling it in Visual Studio, it makes a sound? I know anything might happen because you access out-of-bounds, but isn't that quite unexpected?

Comment: Thank you so much Jonathan Leffler!! I honestly didn't think of that I am going over my allocated memory! So, I tried to make each bigger by 1, and it worked! By the way, I'm using that '\0' because if I don't then my strings won't know when to stop exactly so when the printf comes, it prints more than it should, the '\0' is the only thing that stops it... Neil Edelman, it was very strange as no messages came, but yes the problem was definitely going out of bounds

Comment: Presumably the program printed some output to the terminal - perhaps that was corrupted with a `BEL` character.